# Apply a certain class in tbody tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that hides the rows of the table when I search certain word

`table.find (el + ': not (' + criteria + ')').Parent().hide()`

And this command returns me the not hidden lines, ie, the result of my filter:

```
  console.log(table.find (el + criteria) .parent (). parent ())
```

Result of log:

```
 [tbody, tbody, prevObject: n.fn.init[2], context: table#tableQuest.table.table-striped.table-hover.form-group]
    0: tbody
    1: tbody
    context: table#tableQuest.table.table-striped.table-hover.form-group
    length: 2
    prevObject: n.fn.init[2]
    __proto__: n[0]
```

The filter is working perfectly, but I want to apply this line:

```
$('tbody').parents('table#tableQuest').find('tr:even').not(':first').addClass( 'even' )

.even { background: #f9f9f9; }
```

This line makes the table rows receives alternating colors/striped. But it is being applied to the entire table, I want only the tbody resulting tbody 0 and 1.

When searching for the text '2' ... return the striped rows .. without colliding the same color

fiddle --> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68v4a0gx/13/)

I would be very grateful.

**SOLUTION** https://jsfiddle.net/68v4a0gx/14/

Comment: A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) would be very useful!

Comment: I did the fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/68v4a0gx/7/ When searching for the text '2' ... return the striped rows .. without colliding the same color .. tks

Comment: a find the solution --> https://jsfiddle.net/68v4a0gx/14/

Comment: Well done! If you solve your own question then please submit an answer for it and mark it as solved! This might help other people in future

Comment: How do this line `$('tbody').parents('table#tableQuest').find('tr:even').not(':first').addClass( 'even' );` be equivalent to this `$("#tableQuest tr:visible:even").not(':first').addClass("even")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('tbody').parents('table#tableQuest').find('tr:even').not(':first').addClass( 'even' );
     
 });


//funtion filter row

$('table#tableQuest').each(function(){
    var table = $(this)
    var headers = table.find('th').length
    var filterrow = $('<tr>').insertAfter($(this).find('th:last()').parent())
 
  for (var i = 0; i < headers; i++){
         filterrow.append($('<th>').append($('<input class="" id="iconified_tabquest'+i+'" style="align:center" placeholder="find...">').attr('type','text').keyup(function(){   

   table.find('tr').show()
            
            //here
            $('#tableQuest tr').removeClass("even")   
   $('tbody').parents('table#tableQuest').find('tr:even').not(':first').addClass( 'even' ) 
            
            
   
            filterrow.find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
              var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1
              var filter = $(this).val() != ''
              $(this).toggleClass('filtered', filter)
              if (filter){
                  var el = 'td:nth-child('+index+')'
                  var criteria = ":contains('"+$(this).val()+"')"
                  table.find(el+':not('+criteria+')').parent().hide() 
                        
                        //and here
      $('#tableQuest tr').removeClass("even")                        
                        $("#tableQuest tr:visible:even").not(':first').addClass("even")
     
              }
             }) 
         })))
     }
 })
```

```css
.even { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableQuest">
       <thead>
       <tr>


        <th style="width:100%;" id="th_sort_quest_quest">
         <div id="div_sort_quest_quest"><div class="th-inner sortable" id="div_sort_quest_quest">Quest</div></div>
        </th>

       </tr
       </thead>
        
       <tbody>
        <tr class="trDetail" id="trDetail1" style="display: table-row;">
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a class="" data-id="1" href="">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" class="badge2" data-original-title="D">Test test 1</span>
        </a></td> 
       </tbody>
       
       <tbody>
        <tr class="trDetail" id="trDetail1" style="display: table-row;">
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a class="" data-id="1" href="">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" class="badge2" data-original-title="D">Test test 2</span>
        </a></td> 
       </tbody>
       
       <tbody>
        <tr class="trDetail" id="trDetail1" style="display: table-row;">
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a class="" data-id="1" href="">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" class="badge2" data-original-title="D">Test test 3</span>
        </a></td> 
       </tbody>
                                
                                       <tbody>
        <tr class="trDetail" id="trDetail1" style="display: table-row;">
        <td style="text-align:center;"><a class="" data-id="1" href="">
        <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="" class="badge2" data-original-title="D">Test test 22</span>
        </a></td> 
       </tbody>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
even:nth-child(1):{
background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: When searching for the text '2' ... return the striped rows .. without colliding the same color

https://jsfiddle.net/68v4a0gx/7/